# SQL repeat query

Tags: mysql

I have a table options in my database, I have column "question_id". In my table i have some 1000 of records.

What is my requirement in table for colum "question_id" wherever I have 1 i want to replece with 131 and 2 with 132 , 3 with 133 and so on untill 1000 records.

I tried to do something like that..

```
UPDATE `dta`.`options` SET `question_id` = '132' WHERE `id` > 435 AND `question_id` = 1
```

Searching for some kind of a function or operator.
Please help me !!

Example :-

```
UPDATE `dta`.`questions` SET `quiz_id` = '7' WHERE `id` > 131 AND `quiz_id` = 1

UPDATE `dta`.`questions` SET `quiz_id` = '8' WHERE `id` > 131 AND `quiz_id` = 2

UPDATE `dta`.`questions` SET `quiz_id` = '9' WHERE `id` > 131 AND `quiz_id` = 3

UPDATE `dta`.`questions` SET `quiz_id` = '10' WHERE `id` > 131 AND `quiz_id` = 4

UPDATE `dta`.`questions` SET `quiz_id` = '11' WHERE `id` > 131 AND `quiz_id` = 5

UPDATE `dta`.`questions` SET `quiz_id` = '12' WHERE `id` > 131 AND `quiz_id` = 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE dta.options 
SET question_id = question_id + 130
order by question_id
limit 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you just do

```
UPDATE `dta`.`options` SET `question_id` = question_id + 130 WHERE `id` > 435
```